# Particle.js as background in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, particles.js

I am trying to use particle JS as my background in Vue. Problem is, it is not acting as a background but as a component. So further components push it down.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a css problem rather than a vue problem. Can you provide a code sample?

Comment: I fixed it already. You are right. I just included an id to the vue-particles component and moved it upwards with css. Messed up the responsiveness though.